# Error ::Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

What could be wrong ?

```
public int InsertUpdateQues(bllQues objbllQues)
    {


        dsgetQues = objdllQues.InsertUpdateQues(this);  //ERROR here
        return dsgetQues;
    }
```

I see values getting assigned to ALL the above properties, not one is missing.  Whats wrong then?

**EDIT
I found the error..In my dllQue class's insert update method I had two entries as  sqlParam[4] =new... and sqlParam[4] =new...chnaged the 2nd one to 5..
damn..the problem is I KEEP on making silly mistakes! :( How can I avoid this so my time is not wasted this way ???**

Comment: Show us the code for InsertUpdateQues(this). Object reference can be spotted easily by finding which object has gone null.

Comment: It is very easy to  get confused between objdllQues and objbllQues. Could you please change the names of the variables? It will be easier for people reading the code.

Comment: I agree with @Unmesh. Hungarian notation is not recommended in C# development and your variable names are so similar it could easily lead to confusion.

Comment: This code is fairly confusing with the copying of properties, creating of a dependency, assigning to the current object with this,  and then passing it to a method.  Consider extracting the properties on the BLL into a DTO at least and pass that around.  A better scenario is create a model instance and use the repository pattern with an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to use constants for your indexes so that your code would look something like sqlParam[CustomerName] = ...
That would help readability a little and you might catch your mistakes faster.